# PHP deprecated each() substitutions

Tags: php, server, deprecated

I am usually a network systems operator, but a new job responsibility has required me to implement an internal wiki.  After reviewing my options, I decided that the Lessons Learned Server would be the easiest to implement and maintain.  I followed the instructions on the website, and everything appeared fine until I had the product fully set up.

At this point, I noticed several error messages stating that the each() function is deprecated, impeding the core functionality of the program.  As it turns out, the last public release for LLS was in Sep2018.  The files currently contain adoDB V5.19., which was the originating source of the error.

Since I know very little about coding, my only solutions so far have been to download the latest version of adoDB and substitute it, which did not work, and the replace the each() with foreach(), that a comment above had stated each() was only used for memory-saving purposes.  Unfortunately, that threw up a whole other host of errors, and so I turn to the internet for help.

Comment: "_Unfortunately, that threw up a whole other host of errors, and so I turn to the internet for help._" Which were?

Comment: Using an abandoned project that will never get bug fixes and security updates might not be the best choice.  You might look again for something that is still supported.  Amazon AWS self-updating mediawiki for example - https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/TurnKey-GNULinux-MediaWiki-Wikipedias-Wiki-Engine-/B01KVFNUTQ

Comment: Fatal error:
  Uncaught exception 'ParseError' with message: 
syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH)
A stack trace points to another PHP file, labeled ClassLoader.